# Can I get module alias and is it imported globally?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module name. I want to know:

1. Is is imported.
2. If it is, under what alias.

Currently my solution iterates over all modules

```
import types

def getmodules():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__, name

result = getmodules()
next(result)
```

And from that I get pairs `(alias, name)` and I need to iterate till I find my module.

Is there a way to do that without all the explicit iteraion?

Python version: `Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import types as ty

the_module = 'types'

def getmodule(the_module):
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, ty.ModuleType):
            if val.__name__ == the_module:
                return name
    return None

alias = getmodule(the_module)
print(f'Module {the_module} ' + (f'imported as {alias}' if alias is not None 
                                 else 'not imported in current scope'))
```

And no way without the iteration, I mean even a membership check will iterate under the hood